# PnP powershell provisioning gives 401 error with tenant-scope (fullcontrol) app permissions

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I want to create a new sitecollection with PnP Powershell and created an App with /_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx and granted permissions with: /_layouts/15/appinv.aspx.

This is my permission request xml:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

The script is basically:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $tenantAdminUrl -AppId $AppID -AppSecret $AppSecret 

New-PnPTenantSite -Title "title" -Url $newSitename -Owner $adminUser -TimeZone 4 -Force -Wait -Template "STS#0"
```

Errormessage is:

```
New-PnPTenantSite : Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
In C:\Users\xxx\script.ps1:112 Zeichen:4
+ New-PnPTenantSite -Title $projectItem["Title"] -Url $newS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPTenantSite], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.NewTenantSite
```

Tenant scope and FullControl but i get 401 error? How can i get the app permissions to deploy sitecollections?

Answer (score 0):

You should register an app in Azure AD

1. https://portal.azure.com
2. Go to Azure Active Directory
3. Go to App registrations and create a new app
4. Assign API permissions and consent. For creation of sitecollections you'll probably need atleast "Sites.FullControl.All" (SharePoint Online).
5. Set a client secret (for production you might want to use a certificate) under certificates & secrets.
6. You can then connect in PnP PowerShell by using the Application ID (found under Overview) and the client secret.